# Getting the response for REST API using HTTPBuilder

Tags: json, rest, groovy, httpbuilder

I am trying to call a get method(HttpGetJson) to return the response value and use it to get the resp(for response code) and json(for content) values from it. But I get valid outputs only when I return resp and json separately from response.success. If I try to return the response object I only get NULL. Is there any way of returning the response.

```
public static Object HttpGetJson(String url, String path)
        def http = new HTTPBuilder(url)

        //perform a GET request, expecting JSON response
        http.request(GET,JSON) { req ->
            uri.path = path

            //response handler for a success response code
            response.success = { resp, json ->
                return response//using response instead of json or resp returns null
            }
        }

public void testGET()
{

    def url = 'testurl'
    def path = 'testpath'

    //submit a request through GET
    def response1 = HttpUtils.HttpGetJson(url,path)

    println response1
    //println response.statusLine.statusCode
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return a map with both, like `return [resp: resp, json: json]`.

---

IMO you should pass a closure to be executed from `response.success`:

```
static HttpGetJson(String url, String path, Closure success) {
    def http = new HTTPBuilder(url)

    //perform a GET request, expecting JSON response
    http.request(GET,JSON) { req ->
        uri.path = path

        //response handler for a success response code
        response.success = success
    }
}

void testGET() {
    def url = 'testurl'
    def path = 'testpath'

    //submit a request through GET
    def response1 = HttpUtils.HttpGetJson(url,path) { resp, json ->
        println resp
        println json
    }

}
```